# Map getOrDefault VS getOrUseSupplier

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I am starting to learn lambdas and i do not understand why java Map has:

```
getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)
```

and not(working just the same, but if value is absent, then defaultValue will be taken from supplier):

```
getOrUseSupplier(Object key, Supplier<V> defaultValue)
```

Adventages i currently see of current solution:

- defaultValue does not have to be a final/effectively final value
- looks simpler & no need to know lambda syntax

Disadventages:

- If while using getOrDefault we put new object creation, it will be created and passed to GC immidietely(while using supplier, it will not be created at all).

I would like to know if there is any more disadventages of using & having getOrDefault rather than getOrUseSupplier. Could you also tell me if anywhere in java libraries, there is method like this:

```
static <V> V getOrUseSupplier(Map<?, V> map, Object key, Supplier<V> supplier)
```

that tries to take Value from map, and if it does not exist then takes value from Supplier.

Comment: In the `getOrUserSupplier` case, you still create a `Supplier` object that has to be GCed. So the only cost you save over `getOrDefault` is that of running `V`'s constructor (if that has a significant cost).

Comment: Could you tell me how much memory it takes to create supplier, each time a method is invoked?

Comment: @sepp2k Does it really create a new Supplier? Isn't it supposed to be compiled to a static method call, meaning that only one instance of supplier would be created?

Comment: @sepp2k ok i found the answer. Lambdas that are not capturing any variables are created just once and do not take memory for every usage. Lambdas capturing some external vars take some memory(i got 24 bytes for lambda with 1 captured var) each call, until JIT takes care of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest equivalent of `getOrUseSupplier()` in `Map` is named `computeIfAbsent()` which allows for the value to be computed using the key, giving more flexibility than if it only took a `Supplier`. It also stores the computed value in the `Map`, unlike `getOrDefault`. This is because they have distinct use cases and are not really related. While `getOrDefault` is usually used to return a "safe" non-null default value (such as returning empty string instead of a null) indicating that something *should* be in the map, `computeIfAbsent()` implies that something *must* be in the map, and if it's not, it needs to be created or otherwise the internal state of the program is not correct.

The following example ignores the key and just uses the supplier's value.

```
public static <V,T> V getOrUseSupplier(Map<T, V> map, T key, Supplier<V> supplier) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> supplier.get());
}
```

Comment: Notice that `computeIfAbsent` enters the computed value into the map while `getOrDefault` doesn't have side effects.

Comment: Yeah, this is **not** equivalent since `getOrDefault` doesn't change the map while `computeIfAbsent` does.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Edited to include the difference.

Answer (score 14):

I guess it was because not to blow up the Map interface. You can use `Optional.orElseGet(Supplier)` as a workaround (if you don't keep nulls in your map):

```
Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).orElseGet(supplier)
```

Answer (score 8):

[`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet-T-java.util.function.Supplier-) is a nice way to achieve the desired `getOrUseSupplier(Object key, Supplier<V> defaultValueSupplier)` behavior.

```
Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(map.get(key), defaultValueSupplier));
```

Advantages (comparing to other solutions):

- one-liner
- has no side effects on map
- doesn't create any garbage objects (like Optional)
- core java (no libraries required)

Requires Java 9.

I'd be happy to have this convenient method `getOrUseSupplier()` on map itself too.
Maybe in upcoming releases...

**UPD**

I think that [this mail from Brian Goetz](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/009507.html) is the official answer to your original question. Java designers are afraid that programmers will abuse capturing lambdas using this method.

Comment: Good find with the mailing list conversation! I've expanded that its own full-blown answer.

Comment: interesting argument, and they are not afraid of `orElseGet` in `Optional`?

Answer (score 6):

When lambdas were designed, a discussion was had on the [lambda-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/thread.html#9505) mailing list on whether to include a `Supplier` equivalent to `getOrDefault`.  Two reasons were given by Oracle's Brian Goetz for its exclusion from the API: to avoid feature creep of features that don't carry their own weight, and the cost of lambda capture.

#### [Question](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/009505.html)

> Sometimes constructing the default object is too costly and relying on
> the ternary operation is the escape hatch again. A
> Map.getOrDefault(Object,Supplier) would solve this.
>
> Has this been considered before?

#### [Feature creep](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/009506.html)

> Feature creep alert!
>
> getOrDefault barely, and I mean barely, carried its weight.

#### [Cost](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/009507.html)

> BTW, another reason we are reluctant to go Supplier-happy is that there
> is a mismatch between the actual and perceived cost models for lambda
> capture.
>
> Capturing stateless (non-capturing) lambdas is essentially free.
>
> Capturing stateful ones, such as
>
> ```java
>    () -> state.toString()
> ```
>
> currently has a cost comparable to instantiating an inner class instance
> that captures a local variable.  Since the only reason to provide the
> supplier version is cost, even though it may deliver significant cost
> reduction, it may not deliver as much as people expect it will.  So this
> is a small consideration in favor of not leaning on this trick too heavily.
>
> We are looking at VM work that will significantly remove these costs,
> but first we have to get 8 out the door.

Comment: Thanks to Evgeny Kharitonov for finding this mailing list discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149972/1108305

Comment: This is a really, really good answer because it provides nice reasing from someone involved. "We are looking at VM work that will significantly remove these costs, but first we have to get 8 out the door.". Do you know if there have been newer statements? has progress been made on this front?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `getOrDefault()` method you should keep in mind that if your second argument (the default value) throws an exception for some reason, you will get that exception thrown even if the key exists in the map, as the default value is evaluated regardless of the existence of the key. Here is an example:

```java
private static final Map<String, Integer> RANKS = Map.of(
        "A", 9,
        "B", 8,
        "C", 7,
        "D", 6
);

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int value1 = RANKS.getOrDefault("E", 5); // This will work
    final int value2 = RANKS.getOrDefault("A", Integer.valueOf("G")); // Exception!
}
```

As you can see even though the key `A` exists, it will still try to evaluate the default value anyway, which itself throws a `NumberFormatException` in this example.
If you use that hypothetical `getOrUseSupplier()` method (which unfortunately, as @Kayaman already explained, doesn't yet exist natively in Java, and you should implement it yourself), you can do this:

```java
final int value = getOrUseSupplier(RANKS, "A", () -> Integer.parseInt("G")); // This will work
```

Now the exception will be thrown only if the key `A` is missing.