# How to do ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent without assigning the entry to hashmap?

Tags: java

Is there a way to simulate ConcurrentHashmap.computeIfAbsent but not assign the entry to the hashmap. I just need the instance that the method generated when the entry in the hashmap is not yet there. These are running in Thread. So I need it to be thread-safe.

I have tried with sychronized block, but this will hold the entire hash. I want it to be like the computeIfAbsent.

```
synchronized(hashMap) {
    if (hashMap.contains(key)) {
        rs = hashMap.get(key);
    } else {
        rs = createNewInstance();
    }
}


/* this would be perfect, but I don't what the new instance to be in the hashMap */
rs = hashMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> createNewInstance());
```

Comment: Specification for `computeIfAbsent()` says `If the function returns null no mapping is recorded.` Maybe you could implement method `createNewInstance()` returning null, then snippet `rs = hashMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> createNewInstance());` would work as expected :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like:

```
AtomicReference<Foo> holder = new AtomicReference<>();
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
  holder.set(/* compute the value */);
  return null;  // returning null means no value is stored.
});
/* Use holder.get() to access value */
```

but this is a pretty unusual requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` instead.

Comment: the problem with this is the instance will be created even if it is not needed. Is there anything like map.getOrComputeIfAbsent ?

Comment: No, there's no Supplier version for `getOrDefault`. What's your use case, why don't you want it to be put in the map?

Comment: @user3682563 found an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742258/map-getordefault-vs-getorusesupplier) about it, is the `Optional` approach viable?

Comment: I'm not sure Optional is thread-safe. Most likely it is not. I'm afraid a lot of threads with the same key will trigger the createNewInstance.

Comment: @user3682563 but that's what you wanted. You didn't want the value to go into the map, so for the same key 10 calls will generate 10 new instances, whether threads are involved or not. As for Optional, it's thread safe here since it's a local variable. Multiple threads can never be involved with the same `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method. You could use the fact that `get` returns `null` if the value is not present:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Object rs = Optional.ofNullable(map.get("key"))
            .orElseGet(() -> "created instance");
}
```